# Change background colour of a Row of an XAM Data Presenter

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

is there any code that can access the row of a `Datapresenter` from the `SelectedItemChanged` event to alter the background colour of the row programatically?

Something along the lines of:

```
presenterName.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[7].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

This code just collapses a column, but i need something similar to alter a specific row.

Comment: So are you simply wanting to change the background color of the row when it's clicked?  Programmatically?

Comment: Indeed, it will change depending on if an exception is thrown when trying to connect to a specific webservice, hence why i need the C# to change it.

Comment: Did u search / ask this question in Infragistics forums? They must have answer for this as it looks like a typical requirement to be implemented for Infragistics XamDataGrid.

Comment: None of the answers really suit my needs and generally the responses here are faster and a lot more concise.

Answer (score 2):

For this you would want to create a style and use a DataTrigger to control the color of the record.  The target of your style could be the DataRecordCellArea or the DataRecordPresenter.  If you data doesn't expose a property that you can bind to for this purpose than you could use the Tag property of the Record.

Here is an example showing how to conditionally set the background of a record based on the value of a cell in the record:
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=10103

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my use case (I simply added a new column to the record and added code to update its value to control various triggers; would have loved to do it using simple accessors though). On the plus side, I now have a queryable field for every record --which is a good design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to walk down the tree as **DataGridCellsPresenter** is not exposed by default.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow Row = 
                (DataGridRow)((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;

            DataGridCellsPresenter CellsPresenter =
                GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(Row);
        }

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the `SelectionChanged` event for a DataGrid.

```
    private void myDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = myDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        DataGridRow row = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
        row.Background = Brushes.Red;   
    }
```

This will simply change the background color of the row to Red.

EDITED:  Just noticed you were talking about the Datapresenter from Infragistics.  No clue whether this will work for that control.  Probably something to ask on their forums.